# Get children windows of window by handle or pid

Tags: c#, winapi, parent-child

I have handle and pid of main process / window.
I want to get the children of the process / window - only the visual windows with title.

to achieve what I want, I used the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc ewp, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder title, int size);


public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(int hWnd, int lParam); //Delegate used for EnumWindows() callback function.


public void GetChildren()
{
    //Declare a callback delegate for EnumWindows() API call.
    EnumWindowsProc ewp = new EnumWindowsProc(EvalWindow);
    //Enumerate all Windows.
    EnumWindows(ewp, 0);
}

//EnumWindows CALLBACK function
private bool EvalWindow(int hWnd, int lParam)
{
    //Get the ThreadProcessId of the Window.
    IntPtr handle = (IntPtr)hWnd;
    uint currentThreadPid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out currentThreadPid);

    //Check if the Window is children of the current Window (if it is, it will have the same pid).
    if (currentThreadPid != _threadPid)
        return true;

    //Check if Window is Visible or not.
    if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        return true;

    //Get the Window's Title.
    StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(256);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, 256);

    //Check if Window has Title.
    if (title.Length == 0)
        return true;

    //Add new Window to the _childrenhWnd.
    _childrenhWnd.Add(handle);

    return true;
}
```

where `_threadPid` is the pid of the parent.

It works great but I feel there's a better way of doing it instead of going through all the opened windows and filter them.

Am I right? how can I do it better?

I saw something about `EnumChildWindows` but I could achieve the same.

**EDIT:**

Based on RaymondChen comment, I want to clarify what I mean by saying "children":
 1. If you open sticky notes and add notes - the notes are children.
 2. If you open Paint.NET and press (f5, f6, f7, f8) to open the panels
    - these are child windows.
Every window of the program which is not the main (dialogs also) I call children.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's my code after applying Hans's method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder title, int size);


delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);


public void GetChildren()
{
   foreach (ProcessThread processThread in _process.Threads)
   {
       EnumThreadWindows(processThread.Id,
        (hWnd, lParam) => 
        {
            //Check if Window is Visible or not.
            if (!IsWindowVisible((int)hWnd))
                return true;

            //Get the Window's Title.
            StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetWindowText((int)hWnd, title, 256);

            //Check if Window has Title.
            if (title.Length == 0)
                return true;

            _childrenhWnd.Add(hWnd);

            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero);
   }
}
```

didnt need to use `GetWindowLongPtr` because all the owned windows must have title and be visible else I dont really care so these conditions already filter the owned windows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code. Such questions are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the Code Review is in beta (didnt know about its existence). To improve my code I need more viewers so I still, at this point prefer to post it here

Comment: Fair point. But how will that site leave beta if nobody posts there for fear of lack of audience? Looks like a catch-22 :)

Comment: Indeed a catch. I would make another system which let me post it here but redirects me to the Code Review site - could solve both problems.

Comment: Please clarify your terminology. Your use of the term "children" is nonstandard. In standard terminology, child windows are not top level windows. You find standard child windows via EnumChildWindows. But that does not appear to be what you actually want.

Comment: @RaymondChen I dont not what is the correct term to define the windows I refer. I do have 2 examples of what I call "child windows" so you can understand. 1. If you open sticky notes and add notes - the notes are children. 2. If you open Paint.NET and press (f5, f6, f7, f8) to open the panels - these are child windows. Every window of the program which is not the main (dialogs also) I call children.

Comment: As Hans Passant noted, it seems like you are looking for owned windows. But the real question is why you are looking for owned windows. Generally speaking, you should leave other windows alone.

Comment: @RaymondChen I will try Hans's answer later. Regarding your question, I need the owned windows because when hiding Parent window, I want its children to be hidden aswell. hope it make sense now

Comment: Why are you hiding somebody else's windows? How would you like it if somebody hid your windows? (There may be business logic associated with window hiding, and if you just go in and hide them yourself, that business logic will not run.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I am not hiding someone's else windows. The user hide the windows by himself. Search for hiding windows programs over the internet and you'll see what I am talking about

Comment: The user is asking you to hide windows from some program you know nothing about. You do not know what protocol needs to be followed to accomplish this. You could try blindly hiding windows, but then you run into problems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174208/show-sticky-note-using-showwindow-cause-holes-in-the-stickies) because the application needs to follow special rules when hiding and showing windows, rules you do not know and therefore cannot follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you are not actually talking about child windows, EnumWindows() doesn't enumerate them.  These are surely *owned windows*, they stay on top of their owner and get minimized when the owner is minimized.  Used for tool windows and dialogs, like Paint.NET uses.  There is no dedicated winapi function to enumerate owned windows.

You can make it more efficient.  Enumerate the threads in the process, use Process.Threads.  Then for each thread use [EnumThreadWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  GetWindowLongPtr() with GWLP_HWNDPARENT returns the handle of the owner, non-zero if it is an owned window.

Comment: thanks. Edited my original post based on you answer. Btw I didnt need to use GetWindowLongPtr since the IsVisible and HasTitle already filter the owned windows