# Show Sticky Note using ShowWindow cause "holes" in the stickies

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using the following to Show/Hide window by its handle:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

// Win32 API Constants for ShowWindowAsync()
private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

ShowWindowAsync(_hWnd, SW_SHOW); //Show Window
ShowWindowAsync(_hWnd, SW_HIDE); //Hide Window
```

When I hide Sticky Notes and then Show them again it cause visual "holes" in the stickies and I have to close the Sticky Notes and reopen.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

I believe the problem is specific to the Sticky Notes.
I dont know why it happens but I would like to solve it somehow..

I thought about checking if the window is Sticky Notes, and if it is then Open/Close it instead of Show/Hide will act the same but I dont really like it - feels hacky.

Comment: The sticky note program may be hiding the rich text box also. You may want to enumerate the child rich text box and show that also. You can use Spy++ to know what's happening.

Comment: But I use the same command to both Hide and Show them. how is it possible it's hiding all but showing part of the windows?

Comment: The program may be designed such that showing the window requires extra work that can be done only by the program itself. (For example, recreate a DirectX surface.)

Comment: There's one more weird thing I didnt mention. If I click on the close button of any of the notes, the "Are you sure" dialog appears. If I hide the Sticky Notes while the dialog is opened and then show it again - it works perfectly (there are NO holes). I am not sure the Spy++ will help me, though I am not experienced with it enough to use it

Comment: If this is the issue then it would be just a repainting problem. Just do UpdateWinodow/RedrawWindow/InvalidateWindow etc.

Comment: @goths UpdateWindow / RedrawWindow / InvalidateWindow didnt work (based on http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/updatewindow.html?diff=y, http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.redrawwindow and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/RedrawWindowFlags.html)
Maybe I am not doing it right?
One more thing I just noticed > when the windows stuck at the state where there are holes, if I hover the notes - the loading cursor appear like they are not responding.

Comment: @goths problem solved. I changed from `ShowWindowAsync()` to `ShowWindow()` and it solved the problem.

Comment: great! Thanks for informing. You can answer to your own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from `ShowWindowAsync()` to `ShowWindow()` solved the problem.

I dont know why the `ShowWindowAsync()` cause this problem and I wish for an educating answer here but for now, as long as my problem is solved I am happy.